Why is the band diagram of metals similar to that of an empty lattice?
The electrons at the bottom of a band diagram correspond to some of the most tightly bound electrons. Why is it the case that the bottom of the band structure of sodium, for instance, can be well approximated with the band structure of an empty lattice (see pages 21-22 of this document for the band structure of sodium compared to that of an empty lattice)? I would think that the empty lattice approximation would become more accurate with increasing energy since the electrons become less tightly bound to the atoms, but it seems like the opposite is true.

It's called level repulsion. Some bands would rather distort than get close or cross.
The bottom bands don't have the extra bands coming from farther Brillioun zones, so they don't distort until they approach the higher bands at the end of one of those high symmetry directions.
